I have a java algorithm problem that sorts a chessboard according to 3 different sorting algorithms
I have a java algorithm problem that sorts a chessboard according to 3 different sorting algorithms.
Initially it prints the standard chessboard and then an unordered chessboard.
Then it must take that unordered board and use 1 of the 3 sorting algorithms(Quick sort, Bubblesort and Insertion Sort) to step by step modify the position of each of the pieces, until it reaches its correct position on the standard board.
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chessboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] standardBoard = {
            {"BR", "BN", "BB", "BQ", "BK", "BB", "BN", "BR"},
            {"BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP"},
            {"  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "},
            {"  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "},
            {"  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "},
            {"  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "},
            {"WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP"},
            {"WR", "WN", "WB", "WQ", "WK", "WB", "WN", "WR"}
        };

        Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap = createPieceOrderMap(standardBoard);

        System.out.println("Standard Chessboard:");
        printBoard(standardBoard);

        String[][] shuffledBoard = shuffleBoard(standardBoard);

        System.out.println("\nShuffled Chessboard:");
        printBoard(shuffledBoard);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nChoose sorting algorithm (BUBBLESORT, QUICK, INSERTION):");
        String algorithm = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String[][] sortedBoard = sortBoard(shuffledBoard, pieceOrderMap, algorithm);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;

        if (duration > 2400) {
            System.out.println("Sorting took longer than 2400 ms. Actual duration: " + duration + " ms");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorting completed in: " + duration + " ms");
        }

        System.out.println("\nSorted Chessboard:");
        printBoard(sortedBoard);

        scanner.close();
    }

    // Method to print the board
    public static void printBoard(String[][] board) {
        System.out.println("  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H");
        System.out.println(" +------------------------+");
        
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            System.out.print((8 - row) + "|");
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("|" + (8 - row));
        }
        
        System.out.println(" +------------------------+");
        System.out.println("  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H");
    }

    // Method to shuffle the pieces on the board
    public static String[][] shuffleBoard(String[][] board) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] pieces = new String[64];
        int index = 0;

        // Collect all pieces from the board into a single array
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                pieces[index++] = board[row][col];
            }
        }

        // Shuffle the pieces array
        for (int i = pieces.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int j = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
            String temp = pieces[i];
            pieces[i] = pieces[j];
            pieces[j] = temp;
        }

        // Place shuffled pieces back onto the board
        index = 0;
        String[][] shuffledBoard = new String[8][8];
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                shuffledBoard[row][col] = pieces[index++];
            }
        }

        return shuffledBoard;
    }

    // Method to create a mapping of pieces to their indices based on the standard board
    public static Map<String, Integer> createPieceOrderMap(String[][] standardBoard) {
        Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap = new HashMap<>();
        String[] standardArray = flattenBoard(standardBoard);
        for (int i = 0; i < standardArray.length; i++) {
            pieceOrderMap.put(standardArray[i], i);
        }
        return pieceOrderMap;
    }

    // Method to sort the board
    public static String[][] sortBoard(String[][] shuffledBoard, Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap, String algorithm) {
        // Flatten the boards
        String[] shuffledArray = flattenBoard(shuffledBoard);

        // Sort the array based on the selected algorithm
        switch (algorithm) {
            case "BUBBLESORT":
                bubbleSort(shuffledArray, pieceOrderMap);
                break;
            case "QUICK":
                quickSort(shuffledArray, 0, shuffledArray.length - 1, pieceOrderMap);
                break;
            case "INSERTION":
                insertionSort(shuffledArray, pieceOrderMap);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid algorithm selected.");
                return shuffledBoard;
        }

        // Convert sorted array back to board
        return unflattenBoard(shuffledArray);
    }

    // Method to flatten the 2D board into a 1D array
    public static String[] flattenBoard(String[][] board) {
        String[] array = new String[64];
        int index = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                array[index++] = board[row][col];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    // Method to convert a 1D array back to a 2D board
    public static String[][] unflattenBoard(String[] array) {
        String[][] board = new String[8][8];
        int index = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                board[row][col] = array[index++];
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    // Bubble Sort
    public static void bubbleSort(String[] array, Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap) {
        int n = array.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if (compare(array[j], array[j + 1], pieceOrderMap) > 0) {
                    swap(array, j, j + 1);
                    printArray(array);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Quick Sort
    public static void quickSort(String[] array, int low, int high, Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap) {
        if (low < high) {
            int pi = partition(array, low, high, pieceOrderMap);
            quickSort(array, low, pi - 1, pieceOrderMap);
            quickSort(array, pi + 1, high, pieceOrderMap);
        }
    }

    public static int partition(String[] array, int low, int high, Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap) {
        String pivot = array[high];
        int i = (low - 1);
        for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
            if (compare(array[j], pivot, pieceOrderMap) <= 0) {
                i++;
                swap(array, i, j);
                printArray(array);
            }
        }
        swap(array, i + 1, high);
        printArray(array);
        return i + 1;
    }

    // Insertion Sort
    public static void insertionSort(String[] array, Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap) {
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            String key = array[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && compare(array[j], key, pieceOrderMap) > 0) {
                array[j + 1] = array[j];
                j--;
                printArray(array);
            }
            array[j + 1] = key;
            printArray(array);
        }
    }

    // Utility method to swap elements in an array
    public static void swap(String[] array, int i, int j) {
        String temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    // Utility method to compare two pieces based on their position in the standard array
    public static int compare(String piece1, String piece2, Map<String, Integer> pieceOrderMap) {
        Integer index1 = pieceOrderMap.get(piece1);
        Integer index2 = pieceOrderMap.get(piece2);
        if (index1 == null) index1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  // Handle empty spaces
        if (index2 == null) index2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  // Handle empty spaces
        return Integer.compare(index1, index2);
    }

    // Utility method to print array step by step
    public static void printArray(String[] array) {
        System.out.println("Current board:");
        String[][] board = unflattenBoard(array);
        printBoard(board);
    }
}

My problem is that row 1 and 8 are not printed properly, so the order should be: BR BN BB BQ BK BB BN BN BR but instead it is: BQ BK BB BB BB BN BN BN BR BR BR (in the case of 8, and the same happens in 1).
What should I change so that the final result is as expected?

Please don't spam irrelevant tags. And please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

Which algorithm doesn't work?

This seems like a very good opportunity to learn how to debug your programs. For example by using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens.

there is also a logical problem: how should the left and right of each piece be distinguished - for example, the difference between the right BR and the left BR ? How should any algorithm know if a given "BR" must be sorted before (left) or after (right) of the "BQ" , or, worse(?), before or after a "BN"?

I'm not quire sure I fully understand the requirement in the first place: Can the "unordered" board have the pieces anywhere or would they always be in the correct row? Can sorting move them anywhere or do chess rules need to be applied? If the latter then a sort algorithm won't help. Also, as user85421 mentions there's a logical problem: how would your sorting algorithm "know" that order needs to be "BR,BN" to the left and "BN,BR" to the right? What if it found 2 BR to the right, which would it need to move left?

Another likely important question: assuming this is a learning exercise, what's the purpose? Learning about sorting algorithms? Building a "chess game" in the end?

In general, the sort algorithms themselves are not the problem once properly implemented. The problem lies with determining piece order, i.e. should BR be greater or smaller than BN, etc.?
Assuming this is a learning exercise and chess rules don't have to be followed, one approach could be to extend the code by some additional rules to achieve that ordering:

BP are always after any other B* (i.e. in a higher row)
WP are always before any other W*
BQ is before BK, WQ is after WK (normally)
There are 2 of BR, BN, BB, WR, WN, WB so you need additional information to make them unique, e.g. a left/right flag. Then use this flag to sort:

when 2 pieces are the same, left is before right
when 2 pieces are different then

B is before W
for left the order is *R, *N, *B, for right it's the opposite
*Q, *K are after left but before right





Given those rules, especially the left/right flag, you'd probably need to use a different data type than just a string. Ideally make a ChessPiece class or so and create an array of those.
